# Scala Iterator ++ blows the stack

Tags: scala, iterator

I recently notice this bug causing StackOverFlowError in Scala Iterator++ caused by lazy init. Here's the code to make the bug appear.

```
var lines = Source.fromFile("file").getLines()
var line = lines.next()
lines = Array(line).toIterator ++ lines
lines.foreach { println(_) }
System.exit(0)
```

What I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:219)
...
```

It should be caused by this line in scala source (scala.collection.Iterator.scala:208)

```
lazy val rhs: Iterator[A] = that.toIterator
```

As rhs is a lazy init val, when the iterator is used what the name "lines" refers to already changed, and caused a loop reference, which leads to the error.

I noticed [this post](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2323) talks about the problem in 2013. However it seems it has not been fully repaired. I am running Scala 2.11.8 from Maven Repo.

My Question: I can rename the iterator, e.g. "lines2" to avoid this bug, but is this the only way to solve the problem? I feel like using the name "lines" is more natural and don't want to forsake it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reload an `Iterator` using the same `var`, this appears to work. [Tested on 2.11.7 and 2.12.1]

```
scala> var lines = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines()
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> var line = lines.next()
line: String = this,that,other,than

scala> lines = Iterator(line +: lines.toSeq:_*)
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> lines.foreach(println)
this,that,other,than
here,there,every,where
```

But it might make more sense to use a `BufferedIterator` where you can call `head` on it to peek at the next element without consuming it.

**explanation**

`lines.toSeq` <-- turn the `Iterator[String]` into a `Seq[String]` (The REPL will show this as a `Stream` but that's because the REPL has to compile and represent each line of input separately.)

`line +: lines.toSeq` <-- create a new `Seq[String]` with `line` as the first element (i.e. prepended)

`(line +: lines.toSeq:_*)` <-- turns a single `Seq[T]` into a parameter list that can be passed to the `Iterator.apply()` method. @som-snytt has cleverly pointed out that this can be simplified to `(line +: lines.toSeq).iterator`

**`BufferedIterator` example**

```
scala> var lines = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.buffered
lines: scala.collection.BufferedIterator[String] = non-empty iterator
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- note the type

scala> lines.head
res5: String = this,that,other,than

scala> lines foreach println
this,that,other,than
here,there,every,where
```

Comment: Nice! The `Iterator.apply` does `(line +: lines.toSeq).iterator`.

Comment: For the BufferedIterator you mentioned, do I need to create my own implementation? Seems there's no implementation of BufferedIterator and  no method toBufferedIterator

Comment: One more question: when debugging I see the code `line +: lines.toSeq:_*` actually get a stream from `lines` and invoke `+:` on that to prepend `line`. But I don't quite understand how `:_*` can convert a Seq to Stream. Do you mind explaining the code more? Thanks!

Comment: @Harper, I've added an explanation and a `BufferedIterator` example.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks! Your explanation is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Simple capture:

```
scala> var lines = Iterator.continually("x")
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> lines = { val z = lines ; Iterator.single("y") ++ z }
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> lines.next
res0: String = y

scala> lines.next
res1: String = x
```